# Create File in sharepoint mapped directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, custom, file

I am creating a farm solution, I want to create zip file from 2 or more files taken from sharepoint library.

I want to temporarily save these files in my mapped folder ("Layout/MyFolder"). and allow users to download the zipped file from here.

When I try to create file by acessing path using server.mapPath(".."). It fails with error path doesnt exist.

Please help.
If I should try any other approach please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Layouts for temporary storage is not really a good idea to start with (since it is shared between all sites and webs in the entire farm etc.)

Why not use the nice capabilities of a document library to save your .zip file?

It would then be a matter of creating the .zip and adding it to the document library ([one basic example of that here](http://www.nullskull.com/faq/1534/programatically-upload-file-to-sharepoint-document-library.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will be creating zip from a few files selected from a library. Then I want to save that zip in a folder on server from where user will be able to download the zipped file

Comment: I do not see that as a good idea. Why can you not save the file to SharePoint? It will give you more functionality without having to store the file on a physical server. The approach of saving it on the server will for example be very complex if multiple web front ends is / will be used

Comment: Can you please give a sample code for the same. (I.e  creating a zip from multiple files and saving it in SP?)

Comment: Sample code for creating a .zip is a bit off topic. But how to upload it to SP you already have example code for in my answer

Comment: Hi Robert, I have completed the task using other approach. I am using filebytes from SPFile object and using that I am creating zip file in stream, and then saving that to another document library. Without having to save anything on server. Thanks for your comments.